# how to upload structured table data and build QnA bot upon it in Microsoft azure

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I have a structured PDF file with fields such as holiday,Date,Day and location.
 1) Is there any way to upload it and make our azure bot capable of answering questions about this holiday table, apart from creating a separate database and integrating it.

I have tried uploading it in QnA Maker, but I didn't get proper expected response.

```
 since there are more than 100 entries suppose,editing each of it separately in QnA Maker make no sense.
```

Please let me know if bot built in azure provides any of such facility

eg: DATA

Holiday            Date          Day        Location
Independence Day   15-08-2019   Thursday    All Locations
Ganesh Chaturthi   02-09-2019   Monday      Bengaluru,Mumbai

In Bot:

user Query: When do we have holidays for bengaluru location

Bot response: Independence day and Ganesh chaturthi

Comment: QnA Maker expects table data in a tsv or xls. Have you tried using one of those formats instead?

Comment: Have tried in xls format, but it gives entire data of file uploaded as response

Comment: This doc page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported#data-types) has a link to an xls file - use this as the example. I think the column names are the important piece.

Comment: When data is already segregated into different categories, i find no point in creating another xls file with questions in one column and answers in another column.

Comment: The only feasible solution i see is creating a database for it and integrating it with azure bot or use APIs .

Comment: could anyone help me to find an appropriate solution using azure services as entire Bot is in azure.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee proper detection and extraction is to have this info in a table that fulfills the following conditions:

- Has horizontal and vertical lines for all rows and columns
- Header has
  a different style than rest of rows, such as Bold and clearly bigger
  size
- If table will span multiple pages, Repeat same format including
  the table header in subsequent pages

See example[image]